How can I connect 2nd monitor to Dell laptop?
I have a Dell Vostro 15 3530 laptop with an Intel Iris graphic driver. I'd like connect two monitors to it.
I have the following setup:

A Dell monitor connected directly to the laptop using HDMI cable. This works well.
MS USB-C Travel Hub SWV-0009 that is connected to the laptop using USB Type-C entry, and the 2nd monitor connected to the hub using HDMI. This monitor is not displaying anything. It worked on my other Lenovo laptop.

The answers I've found online refer to a situation where the monitor is directly connected to the USB Type-C, which is not the case here.
I've bought this Baseus USB C to HDMI Adapter, 4K@60Hz USB C Docking Station, 7 in 1.
And it still doesn't work. How can I get it to work? Any other settings that could help me setup the 2nd monitor?

The intel driver may not support dual display, or the usb-c might be data only, but you can still make it happen. https://a.co/d/2qKyu5n

Tnx. What is the difference between this and my adapter? MS USB-C Travel Hub SWV-000

The details for that adapter don't state that it has DisplayPort. Do you mean HDMI perhaps, or are you using some converter/adapter?

My bad. I thought it was display port but it is connected using HDMI.

This is what comes up when typing in cmd :
wmic computersystem get model
Vostro 15 3530
Also, please note as per previous comments, this an HDMI connected to my adapter, not display port. I've edited the question as well.

Your Dell Vostro 3530 may have a USB-C port that supports DisplayPort Alt Mode. The manual says this about the USB-C port on the left side:

One USB 3.2 Gen 1 Type-C port with DisplayPort Alt Mode 1.4/Power Delivery (for computers shipped with an aluminum chassis or a discrete graphics card installed)

You yourself must determine whether this applies to your laptop. If the port has a DisplayPort logo next to it, you’re good. If it’s a regular USB logo, unfortunately not. Since the adapters you have don’t work, chances are you’re out of luck.
All USB-C display connections use DisplayPort Alt Mode, whether the display is connected using DisplayPort or HDMI. Just because the adapter you have has an HDMI output does not mean it’s using something else. There is only DisplayPort Alt Mode. (And Thunderbolt, but you’d know. It’s quite expensive. And also uses DisplayPort internally.)
If your laptop does not support DisplayPort Alt Mode, you can still use a DisplayLink USB graphics “card” to have additional displays. These only need a regular USB data connection but are not suitable for anything but office work. So no gaming and limited video capabilities.

Thanks. I would like to clarify. You said "you can still use a DisplayLink USB graphics “card” to have additional displays.". Does that mean I need to replace the actual hardware on my laptop? As I understand, card is the pyhsical hardware

It's not a card, hence the quotes. It's USB, so a USB port is all you need.
